# Routing/bridge issues

Tags: router, linux

im having troubles with raspbian (raspberry's debian) while trying to route two networks.
My network configuration is this (/etc/network/interfaces):

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 192.168.81.3
        netmask 255.255.255.248
        network 192.168.81.0
        broadcast 192.168.81.7
        gateway 192.168.81.1

iface eth1 inet static
        address 10.0.0.1
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        network 10.0.0.0
        broadcast 10.0.0.255
```

And this is what route prints:

```
root@raspberrypi:~# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         192.168.81.1    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
192.168.81.0    *               255.255.255.248 U     0      0        0 eth0

root@raspberrypi:~# route -C
Kernel IP routing cache
Source          Destination     Gateway         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
```

When I execute "cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward" it returns 1, so I assume ipForwarding is running. But the problem is that it is not forwarding packets between network adapters..

I can ping between devices on the same network, but when I try to contact with hosts on the other network it fails...
I don't know what im missing or why is my routing cache empty. Someone knows?

Comment: Have you set the default gateway correctly on your hosts?

Comment: Yep, I have set 10.0.0.1 as gateway on hosts connected to eth1. But when I ping 192.168.81.3 from a host in 10.0.0.0 network it fails

Comment: Sadly, this is off-topic.  Please post on [su]

Comment: 81.3 doesn't know how to get back to 10??? packets flow in both directions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed!

I was so much focused on raspbian, thinking that the issue should be there, and found that my internet (gateway) router on 192.168.81.1 wasnt redirecting 10.0.0.0 back to 192.168.81.3 (raspbian).
So, I manually added the route in 192.168.81.1 and fixed!

Seems that my raspberry was succesfully configured, and I was so blind looking at it that forgot to configure my main gateway (the one who exits to internet).

Im feeling so damn dumb now for that noob fail... T_T

Comment: Next time run tcpdump on the Raspberry Pi to see where the packets are going, maybe that would have helped :)